# PHP4: Json_encode method which accepts multi byte chars

Tags: json, encoding, php4, multibyte

in my company we have a webservice zu send data from very old projects to pretty new ones. The old projects run PHP4.4 which has natively no json_encode method. So we used the PEAR class Service_JSON instead. http://www.abeautifulsite.net/using-json-encode-and-json-decode-in-php4/

Today, I found out, that this class can **not** deal with multi byte chars because it extensively uses [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) in order to get charcodes from the string and replace the chars. There is no mb_ord() implementation, not even in newer PHP versions. It also uses $string{$index} to access the char at a index, I'm not completely sure if this supports multi byte chars.

```
//Excerpt from encode() method

// STRINGS ARE EXPECTED TO BE IN ASCII OR UTF-8 FORMAT
            $ascii = '';
            $strlen_var = $this->strlen8($var);

           /*
            * Iterate over every character in the string,
            * escaping with a slash or encoding to UTF-8 where necessary
            */
            for ($c = 0; $c < $strlen_var; ++$c) {

                $ord_var_c = ord($var{$c});
                //Here comes a switch which replaces chars according o their hex code   and writes them to $ascii
```

we call

```
$Service_Json = new Service_JSON();
$data = $Service_Json->encode('Marktplatz, Hauptstraße, Endingen');
echo $data; //prints "Marktplatz, Hauptstra\u00dfe, Endinge". The n is missing
```

We solved this problem by setting up another webservice which receives serialised arrays and returns a json_encoded string. This service runs on a modern mahine, so it uses PHP5.4. But this "solutions is pretty awkward and I should look for a better one. Does anyone have an idea?

**Problem description**

German umlauts are replaced properly. BUT then the string is cut of at the end because ord returns the wrong chars. . mb_strlen() does not change anything, it gives the same length as strlen in this case.

Input string was "**Marktplatz, Hauptstraße, Endingen**", the n at the end was cut off. The ß was correctly encoded to \u00df. For every Umlaut it cuts of one more char at the end.

It's also possible the reason is our old database encoding, but the replacement itself works correctly so I guess it's the ord() method.

Comment: I just downloaded the `Services_JSON` module and tested it with your input data.  Worked perfectly fine.  I got the same encoding `\u00df` but I'm not missing the final `n`.  What do you get if you do `strlen($your_input_string)`?

Comment: It returns a length of 33. If that is correct our database encoding is faulty. mb_check_encoding() returns false while mb_detect_encoding() returns utf-8.

Comment: If the length is 33 it means that the `ß` is input as single-byte character of `0xDF`, not the UTF-8 representation of `0xC39F`.  I wonder if that could be the issue?

Comment: The problem appears on every umlaut, äüö and ß There must be a difference between json_encode in PHP > 5.2 and encode() in Service_JSON because in json_encode() it works. Do you know how I can detect the proper encoding? my_detect_encoding does not work - it returns UTF-8 but the database seems to use another encoding. I guess UTF-8 is the script files encoding? PhpMyAdmin also shows broken umlauts but when i output strings in the browser, everything is fine.

Comment: For the time being I would recommend manual inspection via hex dump.  The easiest way to do that would be `unpack('H*', $yourstr)`.  If you see the `ß` as `0xC39F` then the database is giving you proper UTF-8 which (in my limited experience with the library) should work with Services_JSON.  If it's giving you the single-byte representation of `0xDF` then I would recommend passing it through `mb_convert_encoding($yourstr, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')` first.
Failing that, we can take this to the StackOverflow chat and hopefully work something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague found out that

```
mb_strlen($var, 'ASCII');
```

solves the problem. We had an older lib version in use which used simple mb_strlen. This fix seems to do the same as your mb_convert_encoding();

Problem is solved now. Thank you very much for your help!